# Modify the address of a one star pointer passed to a void function

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I was experimenting, and wondered if it is possible to change the address of a **single pointer** passed as **argument** to a `void` function.

I already know, that I can just a **pointer to pointer** and change the address of the pointer or just change the function type to **void (*)**. But is it possible to just do that by some sort of **casting** in the `func_p()` function?

```
int num = 2;

void func_p(int *ptr)
{
    ptr = &num; /* this will not work */
}

void func_pp(int **ptr)
{
    *ptr = &num; /* this will work */
}

int *func_ret(int *ptr)
{
    return &num; /* this will work too */
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot change the address of a pointer, but you can change its value.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, I just want it to point to a different variable.

Comment: Succinctly, no. You can modify the copy of the pointer passed to the function, but you can't modify the original.

Comment: What you're doing with `func_pp` is *emulating pass by reference*. C is only pass by value, which means the value in the call is copied into the functions local argument variable.

Comment: I see. Thank you all for your insights!

Comment: The question is the same as changing the value of ***i*** in `int func(int i) { i = 123; }`. The answer is *yes*, but the catch is it only applies inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

when you pass a variable to function actually copy of your variable is sent and if you change value of that in function your variable's value will not change outside of function. you can search about "Call By Reference" and "Call By Value" for more details.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).